# Can EntityManager not assign an id?

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0

Are there specified cases in JPA2 when a merge would not assign the @Id variable ? And yet return a new instance of the entity without firing an exception ?

Say I'm having this hierarchy:

```
@MappedSuperclass
abstract class Bar {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;

  ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "BAR_1S")
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
class Bar1 extends Bar {
  ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "BAR_2S")
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
class Bar2 extends Bar {
  ...
}
```

For a yet to be found reason the instances of Bar1 get an id after the merge() while instances of Bar2 don't. At least that's what it looks like. I've been trying various approaches at no prevail.

It looks like Hibernate (4.1.4.Final) doesn't want to assign an id to instances of that particular class. :-)

The questions I have:

- Did somebody ever had something like this ?
- Can somebody tell me where in Hibernate the id's are set ? So I can debug that part of the code and find out why it skips the assignment. IntelliJ doesn't seem to break on the modification of fields in entities.

EDIT - ENVIRONMENT CONFIGURATION

- OS: LMDE amd64
- Database: MySQL (5.1.61-2) ConnectJ (5.1.17)
- JVM: 1.7.0_04
- Hibernate: 4.1.4.Final
- Spring: 3.1.1

EDIT - CODE

*All* the entity classes are (in)direct subclasses of Bar. There is only one place where @Id is defined. And there a few identical cases of Bar2 that *do* get an id. But specifically Bar2 doesn't.

final Bar1 bar = new Bar1();
  JpaTemplate.merge(bar); <-- gets an id

final Bar2 bar = new Bar2();
  JpaTemplate.merge(bar); <-- has no id

The application is using JpaTemplate of Spring to merge entities. Which runs okay for everything exception that particular class.

So, if I could find the Hibernate class assigning the id I would probably find out what silly detail I overlooked. :-)

Comment: What is the strategy for AUTO and your database? And what's the code you use to merge Bar2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it ! The merge happens in an overloaded method annotated by @Transactional. I was assuming the overloading method would "inherit" the annotation. Which isn't the case apparently.

By annotating the overloading method with @Transactional it seems to work.

Knew it would be a silly thing ...

Answer (score 0):

First note: JpaTemplate is deprecated, and should not be used anymore. It just delegates to the EntityManager's `merge()` method, and both return an entity.

Here's what the JPA spec says about merge:

> If X is a new entity instance, a new managed entity instance X' is
>   created and the state of X is copied into the new managed entity
>   instance X'.

So, if an ID is generated, it will be assigned to the attached entity, and not to the object you pass to the merge method. You should thus never ignore the result of the merge method. Instead of

```
jpaTemplate.merge(bar);
```

you should do:

```
bar = jpaTemplate.merge(bar);
```

Moreover, the JPA spec also says that

> A generated id is not guaranteed to be available until after the
>   database insert has occurred.

And this is probably the other reason why you don't have an ID. AFAIK, the AUTO strategy, with MySQL, consists in relying on an autoincrement ID column in the database, and it's only possible to get the value of the ID after the insert has been done, and Hibernate waits until absolutely necessary to flush, and thus perform the insert. If you really need to have the ID right after the merge, do the following:

```
bar = jpaTemplate.merge(bar);
jpaTemplate.flush();
Long id = bar.getId();
```